How to plot data with two different hues with different multiple for each?
I'm trying to plot a distribution of lesions by age group for two different ancestry groups.
For now, I have made two separate plots of said distribution, but I want to put them in the same plot but not in a multiplot, I want each ancestry group to be side by side, so multiple="dodge", but I also want to visualize the distribution of lesion with multiple="stack"
Here is how I am doing it:
plot1 = sns.displot(x='age-group', hue='macroCIDDiagnostic', data=dataset[isAnalisedLesion & isPomeranMask], 
                    aspect=1, height=4, stat="count", multiple="fill", shrink=.8, hue_order=["L57.0", "C80", "C44.9"])

plot2 = sns.displot(x='age-group', hue='macroCIDDiagnostic', data=dataset[isAnalisedLesion & isntPomeranMask], 
                    aspect=1, height=4, stat="count", multiple="fill", shrink=.8, hue_order=["L57.0", "C80", "C44.9"])


here is how I want it:

also if possible how would I change the color pallet for each group?

Looks like you need to build more groups. Anyway, please provide a [mre] (data + code).
